# Apple connect IAP - Get custom code from Apple Connect API

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

## Issue

Currently I have multiple **subscription offers** available for yearly/monthly subscriptions. Each of the **subscription offers** have multiple different **custom codes** available. When the customer buys a subscription and the receipt is being handled in the backend, I need to know which of the custom codes was used.

When i call the https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt I get the values **offer_code_ref_name** and **promotional_offer_id**. The offer_code_ref_name is the subscription offer name AND NOT the custom code.

I tried to get more info using the [https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/subscriptions/{transactionId](https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/subscriptions/%7BtransactionId)} request, but it does not give me any info about the custom code used either.

I do however see which custom code has been used if I go to **Sales and Trends > Sales and Trends Reports** and download **Subscritpion Reports** (in apple connect dashboard). There the offer code can be found ref. as **"Promotional Offer ID"**

## My question

How can I get which custom code was used when purchasing a renewable subscription using transaction id or transaction Receipt?